# Exchange 2010 Transition: Some sent emails rejected

Tags: exchange-2010

I have just recently transitioned from Exchange 2003 to Exchange 2010. Both 2k3 and 2k10 are up. All mailboxes are still on 2k3. We have having no *significant* issues at this time. Most users are able to send and receive email without issue.

However, some users are occasionally getting outbound email rejected.

```
mtain-db05.r1000.mx.aol.com gave this error:
: (CON:B1) http://postmaster.info.aol.com/errors/554conb1.html 
There's a problem with the recipient's mailbox. Please try resending this message. If 
the problem continues, please contact your helpdesk.
```

AND

```
TX2EHSMHS034.bigfish.com rejected your message to the following e-mail addresses:
email address omitted
TX2EHSMHS034.bigfish.com gave this error:
Service unavailable; Client host [71.183.125.162] blocked using Blocklist 1, mail 
from IP banned; To request removal from this list please forward this message to
delist@messaging.microsoft.com and include your ip address 71.183.125.162 .
```

I checked mxtoolbox and I am not blacklisted. AKAIK my mail *should* be coming from 71.183.125.163, but some of these outbound emails are reporting .162. I think I can narrow it down between the 2k10 box and the firewall.

***EDIT*** I just confirmed that mail used to (before the transition) come from .163. Now its all coming from .162. This is probably the issue. I am not sure what's responsible for the originating IP? My Sonicwall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I checked mxtoolbox and I am not blacklisted

Maybe denial is one of the five stages of IT problems.

http://domain-blacklist.e-dns.org/mail.orangetown.com

```
LISTED  572ms   APEWS Level 2
    DNS A Record orangetown.com. resolves to a blacklisted IP 71.183.125.162
    DNS MX Record (Mail Server) mail.orangetown.com. resolves to a blacklisted IP 71.183.125.163
LISTED  115ms   ATLBL ABL
    DNS A Record orangetown.com. resolves to a blacklisted IP 71.183.125.162
    DNS MX Record (Mail Server) mail.orangetown.com. resolves to a blacklisted IP 71.183.125.163
etc. etc.
```

> I just confirmed that mail used to (before the transition) come from .163. Now its all coming from .162. This is probably the issue. I am not sure what's responsible for the originating IP? My Sonicwall?

Yes. It likely has a 1-1 NAT entry from your Exchange 2003 server's internal IP address to the .163 public address, and your new Exchange 2010 server has a different internal IP therefore is going out to the internet via the normal default public IP of .162.

What to do about it depends on your plan for finishing migration - changing this might also affect which server OWA goes to, and therefore which SSL certificate is presented to the world, and it could also be tied to DNS names or protocols unrelated to Exchange.

Alternately, you would have to set up another address - .162 or a spare one - with the right DNS, reverse DNS, firewall rules and so on to make it live.

Either way you will probably have to apply to be removed from any blocklist you can find.

Comment: It ended up being the outbound NAT policy. Since there wasn't one it was defaulting to the 162 WAN IP address. So like I said, I wasn't blacklisted. I was just sending from the wrong address that was blacklisted!